# WPML with Subdomains behaves very strange in combination with multiple environments

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I'm currently working on a clients website where we want to split up the live environment into three different ones.

We currently want the following envs:

- Production (Live website)
- Preview (Unpublished live website for content management)
- Staging (Development state for feature and development previews)

We have them setup via the following subdomains:

**Live**:

- de.xyz.com
- en.xyz.com
- ch.xyz.com

**Preview**:

- de.preview.xyz.com
- en.preview.xyz.com
- ch.preview.xyz.com

**Staging**:

- de.staging.xyz.com
- en.preview.xyz.com
- ch.preview.xyz.com

**NOTE**: We're also using the WP cache with advanced-cache.php in combination with WP Engine Advanced Cache. Maybe thats a conflict?

Anyway, when I now login to the different backends and try to map the subdomains and save somehow the environments overwrite each others settings again, even though they are on separated webservers and use separated databases.

I'm really confused because when I for example set `en.preview.xyz.com` on the preview domain, somehow the same `en.preview.xyz.com` value is set on the staging environment.

Are there any known conflicts with WPML Subdomains and multiple Websites on the same parent domain or a caching plugin?

Thanks already a lot. My client already is kind of annoyed because the content managers are waiting.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my problem.

Basically the WP Supercache Plugin was setup wrong to work with different environments. I had to load the `WP_CACHE_KEY_SALT` from the .env-files in the `object-cache.php`